# HTML / CSS - Centering FOOTER at the Bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I am trying to place the **Footer** on the **Bottom Center** of my page
but **nothing is working**, I don't know **if it is a Code that is
blocking it to go down**, but I am sure it is!

I am new to HTML and CSS! Please advise!

Below is my **full HTML and CSS code**!

Thank you so much for your help!

**PS**: **I don't want to change my current code** as it is working **Perfectly Fine**,
I just want to **place the Footer** on the **Bottom Center** of my page!

(**Exactly as the NavBar**)

**Please try it** on your **Editor** for better understanding!

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../images/body_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
  filter: saturate(2);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
  color: white;
}

.social {
  float: right;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 445px;
  top: -11px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
}

img {
  top: 7px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 181px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
  filter: saturate(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Home</a>
  <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-wallet"></i> Portfolio</a>
  <a href="contact.html"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-user"></i> Contact</a>
  <a href="about.html"><i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i> About</a>
  <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="logo"></a>
  <div class="social">
    <a class="facebook" href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp Facebook</a>
    <a class="instagram" href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank" title="Instagram"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp Instagram</a>
    <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" title="Twitter"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>&nbsp Twitter</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p id="footerdesc">Made with love by BS INDUSTRIES! Check out my social media: </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code to `.footer` will put the footer at the bottom of the screen. I would explain how the code works but I think you'll be better off learning about positioning in a well-made tutorial.

(The code will put the footer at the bottom of the screen; if you scroll, the footer will stay at the bottom of the screen. If you want your footer to be at the bottom of the page, possibly hidden depending on scroll position, please clarify so in your question.)

```css
position: fixed;
bottom: 8px;
left: 8px;
right: 8px;
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This worked exactly the way i wanted! No, I want the footer to stay there and visible! This is exactly what i wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Good luck, Try to add the following properties in footer selector.

```css
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
```

```css
.footer { 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
  filter: saturate(2);
}
```